# java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 3, Size: 3

Tags: java

I keep getting

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 3, Size: 3
at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(Unknown Source)
at java.util.ArrayList.get(Unknown Source)
at hartman.ShortestString.printShortestString(ShortestString.java:40)
at hartman.ShortestString.main(ShortestString.java:28)
```

How do i fix this?

```
package hartman;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ShortestString {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.printf("WELCOME TO SHORTEST STRING\n\n");
        System.out.printf("Type \".\" when done entering data.\n\n");

        ArrayList<String> myArray = new ArrayList<>();
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        boolean keepAsking = true;

        while (keepAsking) {
            System.out.printf("Enter string: ");
            String userInput = keyboard.nextLine();

            if (userInput.equals(".")) {
                keepAsking = false;
            } else {
                myArray.add(userInput);
            }
        }

        printShortestString(myArray);
        System.out.printf("\n\nGOODBYE!\n");
        keyboard.close();
    }

    public static void printShortestString(ArrayList<String> myArray) {

        int index;
        int index1 = 1;

        for (index = 0; index < myArray.get(index).length(); index++) {
            if (myArray.get(index).length() < myArray.get(index1).length()) {
                System.out.printf("\nShortest string is \"%s\" with length %d",
                        myArray.get(index), myArray.get(index).length());
            } else {
                index1++;
            }
        }
        return;
    }
}
```

Comment: The title of the post should reflect the issue

Comment: Can you point us to which line 40 is?

Comment: Should `for (index = 0; index < myArray.get(index).length(); index++) {` be `for (index = 0; index < myArray.get(index1).length(); index++) {`? You're incrementing through an array and using the counter while comparing and it's causing issues.

Comment: 40 is for (index = 0; index < myArray.get(index).length(); index++) {

Comment: So you're looping through all strings, until you get to one who's length isn't bigger than the index that it's found at? That definitely doesn't sound like the right logic.

Comment: @Adam: That looks like a good catch to me.

Comment: Every time I see Sanner, I'm feeling something to be wrong on the way

Answer (score 2):

Try using `for (index = 0; index < myArray.length(); index++) {` for line 40. You're using the length of the string at element `index`, not the length of the ArrayList.

Answer (score 1):

Your method seems to have problem.

```
public static void printShortestString(ArrayList<String> myArray) {
    if (myArray.isEmpty()) return;
    int len = myArray.get(0).length();
    int shortestIndex = 0;
    for (int index = 1; index < myArray.size(); index++) {
        if (myArray.get(index).length() < myArray.get(index - 1).length()) {
            len = myArray.get(index).length();
            shortestIndex = index;
        } 

    }
    System.out.printf("\nShortest string is \"%s\" with length %d",
                myArray.get(shortestIndex), len);
    return;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

We'll need to see the source of `printShortestString()`, but I'll bet you need to change your for loop to break when the index, `i`, is one less than the length of your array, as opposed to equal to the length of the array:

```
for {i=0; i < myArray.length(); i++) {
...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This line causing you to go out of index:

```
for (index = 0; index < myArray.get(index).length(); index++)
```

You want to iterate over the size of array :

```
for (index = 0; index < myArray.size(); index++)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your logic behind `printShortestString(...)` is incorrect.  You want to loop through the list size (not the String size).  What's happeneing here is:

```
myArray   .get(index)                             .length()
list      object at a given index of this list    size of that object
```

What you want is:

```
myArray  .size()
list     size of list
```

Change:

```
for (index = 0; index < myArray.get(index).length(); index++) {
```

To:

```
for (index = 0; index < myArray.size(); index++) {
```

Comment: the assignment is to find the string with the smallest length

Comment: @Xyphoris That's fine.  Just access the length inside the loop. Not in the loop header.

Answer (score 0):

```
String word = null;
for (index = 0; index < myArray.size(); index++) {

    if (word == null) {
        word = myArray.get(index);
        continue;
    }

    if (myArray.get(index).length() < word.length()) {
        word = myArray.get(index).length()
    }
}
System.out.println("The shortest word is:" + word );
```